# git grep main repo and specific submodules

Tags: git

I have two submodules in a main repository that are tightly coupled with the code in the main repository. So much so that when performing a git grep, I'd like the main repo to be grepped along with those two specific submodules. I can't do a full git submodule foreach "git grep ... || true", because I have other submodules that are very large, and grepping through those submodules can take up to 15-20 seconds for each of them.

So, I need a more specific solution than git submodule foreach, that allows me to specify the specific submodules to grep though, along with grepping my main repo.

My two submodules are `foo` and `submodules/bar`

Here's my current solution. This allows me to say `git gpx -i something.*interesting`, etc. I'm still new at creating git aliases, so I'm hoping this solution can be improved.

```
[alias]
    inr = "!f() { cd $1 && $2 ;}; f"
    gprs = "!f() { for r in $1; do git inr $r \"git grep $2\" | perl -pe \"s|^|$r/|\"; done ;}; f"
    gpx = "!f() { git grep $*; git gprs 'foo submodules/bar' \"$*\" ;}; f"
```

EDIT: One problem I discovered is that I lose quotes around the regex, so I cannot call something like this: `git gpx -i "foo bar"`, because it gets translated to this: `git grep -i foo bar`. I can't think of a clean way to avoid this.

Comment: Seems to me, it's the best you can get.

Comment: What happens if you wrap the first `$*` in double quotes?

Comment: @Cupcake Then you lose the ability to pass flags (e.g., -i) to the command.

Comment: all submodules: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18810904/how-to-git-grep-the-main-project-and-all-submodules

Comment: @CiroSantilli烏坎事件2016六四事件法轮功  Good that this sort of need is being incorporated into the core git command library. I just took a look at my post after years and this syntax looks cryptic. This is best solved with tools other than hacky git aliases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**REDO**: I had hacked together a bash script with that script to do the paging (mentioned at the bottom), but noticed that your example already prefixed the search path. I modified your alias a little bit and now find that this works for me:

```
[alias]
    gpx = "!f() { list=$1; shift; for r in . $list; do ( cd $r; git grep $@ | perl -pe \"s|^|$r/|\"; ); done ;}; f"
```

If you use a subshell then you can fold in the "inr" functionality "( cd $1; cmd; ... )" (since it isolates the chdir), and if you add a "." then it will search the supermodule as well.
I tested it out with something like

```
git --no-pager gpx 'foo submodules/bar' --color=always -nIE '\w+\(\w*\)' | less -R
```

It seems to work well with escaping (was going to use `git-rev-parse --sq-quote` but seems like git handles that for you already). This seems more elegant than the script stuff listed below, and maybe I could use your style of aliases with the function prefix and replace / simplify a lot of that functionality. That being said, thanks for showing that!

Tried to make another alias that use `gpx` for the pager stuff, but that got a little hairy with escaping, so I just made another alias as well:

```
[alias]
   gpxp = "!f() { list=$1; shift; for r in . $list; do ( cd $r; git --no-pager grep --color=always $@ | perl -pe \"s|^|$r/|\"; ); done | less -R ;}; f"
```

Then it becomes

```
git gpxp 'foo submodules/bar' -nIE '\w+\(\w*\)'
```

*NOTE*: If you get errors, those will show up in the grep text results.

**ORIGINAL**:

I had run into [similar problems](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/217392/focus=217429) with escaping and using git aliases.

I've been writing up a small extension to `git-submodule` which allows you to do constrained iteration. The help for the feature is in `git-submodule-ext foreach [-c | --constrain]` ([help](https://github.com/eacousineau/util/blob/46b32e5/git-submodule-ext.sh#L37), [implementation](https://github.com/eacousineau/util/blob/8110b1f/git-submodule-ext.sh#L176)). The install instructions are here: [README](https://github.com/eacousineau/util#setup)

If you wish to constrain iteration to `foo` and `something/bar`, in your supermodule you can do

```
git config scm.focusGroup 'foo something/bar'
```

Then to do your greppage

```
git --no-pager submodule-ext foreach -t -r -c -k git grep 'expression'
```

Or if you install with aliases,

```
git --no-pager tsfer -c -k git grep 'expression'
```

The `git --no-pager` option is to prevent each submodule from pulling up `$GIT_PAGER` after each search. I added a `--keep-going` option to the script so that if grep returned nothing (resulting in non-zero status), it doesn't stop iterating. The other solution is to do the example in submodule docs, using `git tsfer -c -k 'git grep "expression" || :'`, which work equivalently.

If your expression is complex, something like looking for function calls `'\w+\(\w*\)'`, you will need to enclose the entire expression in double quotes:

```
git --no-pager tsferp -c -k "git grep -E '\w+\(\w*\)'"
```

If escaping is a huge issue and you're using bash, you export a function to use in the iteration (the extension script I modified is using `bash`, rather than Git's standard `/bin/sh`)

```
greppage() {
    git grep -E 'some(really)?complex.*\(expression\)'
}
export -f greppage
git --no-pager tsfer -c -k greppage
```

Hope that helps.

NOTE: A current drawback to this is that it might be hard to figure out which submodule the match was located in. A fix could be made by somehow prepending the `$name` of the submodule, but I looked the `git grep`'s options and could not find anything like that. I tinkered with the command a little bit and came up with this, uhh, 'compact', command:

```
git --no-pager sube -q foreach -t -r -c -k "echo [ \$name ]'\n'; git grep --color=always -E '\w+\(\w*\)'; echo '\n\n'" | less -R
```

This make the foreach quiet (suppress the 'Entering' output), and add some braces and newlines to make it easier to see divisions among submodules. Lemme see if I can make a function / alias for this to make it easier.

**EDIT**: Here's the hacked together script, which is not as elegant. I just made it a bash function to simplify things

```
git-greps() { git --no-pager sube -q foreach -t -r -c -k "git grep --color=always $(git rev-parse --sq-quote "$@") | perl -pe \"s|^|\$name/|\"" | less -R; }
```

Example

```
git-greps -nIE '\w+\(\w*\)'
```